# `Alt-f` or `Alt-b` then `d` deletes the forward word rather than putting character 'd' in front of the word. Why does emacs behave in this way?

Tags: text-editing, keystrokes

I was doing some editing in Emacs. I was using `Alt-f` and `Alt-b` to traverse by word. I wanted to add the character `d` in front of a word. So I pressed `Alt-b` to get to the front of the word and then pressed `d`. Oops! It deleted the word rather than putting `d` in front of the word.

Is the expected behavior of Emacs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ALT-d` is normal for delete word, so my guess is that you pressed the d key before releasing the `ALT` key. Don't forget you can check any keystroke combinations by using `C-h c`, that is `C-h` then release the Control key and press `c`. Enter the key strokes.